# How to create custom events?

Tags: iphone

I have a view1 with a subview view2, where i have a UIButton button that has fires an action soSomething:

```
view1
--view2
----IBOutlet UIButton *button
-----(IBAction) doSomethingid)sender
```

clicking the button calls doSomething.
now how can i dispatch a custom event in doSomething and catch it at the view1?

eg in view2:

Code:

```
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender{
  // Disptach the event for the parent "superView" to receive

}
```

then in view1 have something that handles that event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your action event

```
// Dispatch the event for the parent "superView" to receive
-(IBAction) doSomething:(id)sender{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"SomeEventName"];
}
```

in your `view1 viewdDidLoad` method write this code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(methodToHandel) name:@"SomeEventName" object:nil];
```

and add this method to handle that event

```
-(void) methodToHandel{
    // this method get call 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSNotificatons or delegation depending on how your app is set up. I'd suggest looking at the docs to learn more about these things.